# Is there any way to rate limit Kinesis Consumer?

Tags: amazon-kinesis, rate-limiting

I have a use case where I want to call an external API which use rate limiting. Let's assume for now we are allowed to call 10 API's every 5 seconds.

I want to use a Kinesis Data Stream to fulfil my use case. I will produce events using the Kinesis Producer on the Stream and I want to setup multiple consumers that consume from the same stream. These consumers should then call the external API respecting the rate limit.

The problem is since I have 2 instances of the consumer running as 2 different EC2 instances, I am not able to think of any approach where these 2 consumers can work together and decide that they need to make only 10 calls to the external API every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

One such solution which can fit in is to use a distributed rate limiter library, the below library is one such which supports redis sliding window rate limiter: https://github.com/mokies/ratelimitj
Needs additional infra and cost for redis/elastic-cache